# Use .env file on Azure Pipeline's Docker@2

Tags: docker, azure-devops

So, my issue is that i need to import a .env file during the docker build part of the Docker@2 task on Azure.
Something like this, but -hopefully- using Docker@2

`docker run --env-file envvariables.env project`

I know that i can pass the variables independantly using the args like this

`--build-arg VAR=$(VAR)`

But the issue is that i have ***A LOT*** of enviroment variables in that file, so this solution becomes kinda unsustainable

I need to pass out the .env file to the build process on Docker@2

Answer (score 0):

Tested from my side, Docker@2 does not support using .env files directly. You need to use `--build-arg key=value` in the arguments. When building an image from a Dockerfile, the supported arguments are as follows:

[image]